# Converting low volt (2.7), high amperage, (6) to a higher voltage at 90%+ efficiency

Tags: power-supply, dc-dc-converter, solar-cell

I have a solar panel set up which produces 2.7v at 6 amps and I want to increase that voltage to around 5-10 volts with reduced amperage at around a 90+% efficiency. The problem is that the voltage is too low to power a 555 timer driven boost converter and that a joule thief severely limits the output current.

I'm thinking of using a self-oscillating boost converter that will utilize an LC circuit to produce a sine wave which will then drive the boost converter, but I fear that my electronics skills and lack of an oscilloscope or any way to measure inductance will severely limit that idea.

Does anyone have any suggestions that would be simple and effective? (My current level of electronics knowledge is all theory from physics and some practical.)

Comment: Can't you rewire the panel for higher voltage? Efficiency would be higher.

Comment: @TEMLIB Problem is that the panel I'm using is limited by space and so only a maximum of 6 cells can be used which each have a max voltage of 0.5V. This setup produces the maximum voltage possible.

Comment: If you want to get anywhere close to that efficiency (and I'm not sure it's possible with a blocking oscillator topology, anyway), you may want to consider IGBTs. One thing going for you is that your boost requirements may be modest, as little as 2:1. The thing making it more difficult is that some overhead voltage is likely required and this margin destroys efficiency. You have, at most, only a quarter-volt of overhead to squander at the source voltage. This makes "easier ideas" unworkable. Your oscilloscope needs are very modest and you can afford one, as well as an LC meter, I'd think.

Comment: Also, your construction techniques will, entirely on their own, affect the efficiency you achieve. Every part detail also starts to matter when you try to approach 90+% efficiency. The entire system designed and built as a whole piece, parasitics included. New tiny details become the new critical path problem as you remove older, problems. It's like designing a race car. You figure "more horsepower" for higher speeds and "more torque" for quick get-up-and-go, and find that the transmission isn't up to it. Replace that, then the axles. Replace those, and it's tire-to-ground. Etc. It never ends.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm currently trying to learn more about electronics and every bit is fascinating. It's a shame though that those efficiencies aren't going to be very likely. I think I'll just build a second panel and wire it in series.

Comment: Use a low power boost converter to provide a higher voltage to power the controller that can then supply good gate drive to the main MOSFET switches.

Comment: Companies that make SMPS controller ICs usually offer Evaluation Kit / Reference Design PCB layouts; if at all possible try to follow those as closely as possible. Don't even try using a solderless breadboard for this type of project, the parasitic effects will be significant.

Answer (score 1):

No need to overcomplicate things.

Texas TPS61096A will solve all your issues.

[TI](https://www.ti.com/product/TPS61096A)

Linear LTC3119 with MPPC (fixed point MPPT) would be even better due to your solar input.

[Linear](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc3119.html#product-overview)